Animating `TabBar` visibility transitions in SwiftUI
I have a tabbed view which at some point pushes a full screen view to show some screenshots; for this specific screen I'm hiding the TabBar using the modifier.-
.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)

Now, when I pop back, the TabBar reappears in a non graceful way (it just appears with no animation). In SwiftUI I typically create animations with the withAnimation operator, but in this case I have no place to use unless I override the back button to handle the event myself (still not sure if this would work anyway)
Is there any way to automatically force the animation to hide / show the TabBar as in the traditional UIKit way?:
self.navigationController.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)


If you use .fullScreenCover then the tabbar is covered too, there is no need to hide it.

Thank you @BenzyNeez, it might do the trick but I'm pushing the view, not presenting modally which I guess is what fullScreenCover modifier works with, right?

Not sure what you mean by pushing the view. Can you show an MRE please?

Sorry, I tried to at first, but it's quite a complex view not trivial to extract an MRE. Anyway, @Mojtaba approach did the trick for me :) Thanks again!

You can depend the visibility to a simple State variable and toggle it with animation like:
@State private var isVisible = true
,,,

.toolbar(isVisible ? .automatic : .hidden, for: .tabBar)
.animation(.default, value: isVisible)



Thank you @MojtabaHosseini, yep, that might be a good approach but unfortunately still involves overriding the back button, which ideally I would prefer not to.

No you don't need to override the back button, You just need to pass the isPresented or any other value that is responsible for presenting the next page as the value argument of the animation and the toolbar visibility condition

Thank you @MojtabaHosseini, yes, it works! And using isPresented seems I don't even need the @State var, thanks!

This solution doesn't feel like a natural animation for the tabBar.  If you look at the tabBar on whatsapp when selecting a chat it slides out nicely and back in when navigating back.  I can reproduce this behavior bywrapping the tabView within a navigationStack rather than using a separate navigationStack for each tab.  But other issues arise doing that and it seems most people recommend against that design.

As I mentioned in a comment, if you use .fullScreenCover then the tabbar is covered too, so there is no need to hide it.
However, you said you are "pushing" the covering view. I assume you mean, you are navigating to a child view in a NavigationStack. If this is correct, then you could change the visibility of the tabbar in .onAppear and .onDisppear, using withAnimation where required:
@State private var tabbarVisibility = Visibility.visible

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Show cover") {
                    Text("All covered")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(.yellow)
                        .onAppear {
                            tabbarVisibility = .hidden
                        }
                        .onDisappear {
                            withAnimation {
                                tabbarVisibility = .visible
                            }
                        }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .padding(.top, 300)
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
            }
            .toolbar(tabbarVisibility, for: .tabBar)
        }
        .tabItem { Label("One", systemImage: "1.circle") }
    }
}



Thank you for the further clarification @BenzyNeez, for the record, your solution is working too :)
